# How to display the paypal button using vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, paypal

How can I show up the button of paypal in vuejs? I already tried these below, it shows **build successfull** but the button does not show up. And bdw the input field shows, only the button not.

Is this really impossible to happen, paypal in vuejs?

```
<template>
    <div id="container">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <div id="paypal-button"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script> 
    export default {
        mounted() {
            paypal.Button.render({
                env: 'sandbox',
                client: {
                    sandbox: 'ARQ-WKAkFn3g4C111Ud3lLaUAfzagvJ_pmkLKBVMASvv6nyjX3fv3j0gtBdJEDhRPznYP9sLtf9oiJfH',
                    production: 'EFNo9sAyqiOmnlRHsAdXiGBf6ULysEIfKUVsn58Pq6ilfGHVFn03iVvbWtfiht-irdJD_df1MECvmBC2'
                },

                locale: 'en_US',
                style: {
                    size: 'medium',
                    color: 'gold',
                    shape: 'pill',
                },

                commit: true,

                payment: function(data, actions) {
                    return actions.payment.create({
                        transactions: [{
                            amount: {
                                total: '11',
                                currency: 'USD'
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                },

                onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                    return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                        window.alert('Thank you for your purchase!');
                    });
                }
            }, '#paypal-button');

            console.log('notification mounted');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Error in my console:

> ReferenceError: "paypal is not defined"

---

I also tried other functions `created()`, and `init()` but still doesn't show.

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: @Jerodev `Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: paypal is not defined" `

Comment: You import a script (`checkout.js`) which will create a `paypal` object/class on your window object. So if you want to access it simply do `window.paypal`. (Make sure you check if it's defined before)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shows you these `ReferenceError: "paypal is not defined"` because you fail to import the **js file** of paypal.

So here's how you do it, first install npm:

```
npm install --save-dev vue-plugin-load-script
```

And add these code inside your **app.js**:

```
import LoadScript from 'vue-plugin-load-script';

Vue.use(LoadScript);
```

And you can now import the js file of paypal and execute the paypal codes:

```
Vue.loadScript("https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js").then(() => {
    mounted() {
        paypal.Button.render({
            env: 'sandbox',
            client: {
                sandbox: 'ARQ-WKAkFn3g4C111Ud3lLaUAfzagvJ_pmkLKBVMASvv6nyjX3fv3j0gtBdJEDhRPznYP9sLtf9oiJfH',
                production: 'EFNo9sAyqiOmnlRHsAdXiGBf6ULysEIfKUVsn58Pq6ilfGHVFn03iVvbWtfiht-irdJD_df1MECvmBC2'
            },

            locale: 'en_US',
            style: {
                size: 'medium',
                color: 'gold',
                shape: 'pill',
            },

            commit: true,

            payment: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.payment.create({
                    transactions: [{
                        amount: {
                            total: '11',
                            currency: 'USD'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },

            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    window.alert('Thank you for your purchase!');
                });
            }
        }, '#paypal-button');

        console.log('notification mounted');
    }
});
```

[full documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-plugin-load-script)

Comment: See @belvederef answer

Answer (score 7):

In 2021, I recommend having a look at their new official npm package at https://github.com/paypal/paypal-js, so you can do:

```
<template>
  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { loadScript } from '@paypal/paypal-js';

...
async mounted() {
  const paypalSdk = await loadScript({
    'client-id': 'YOUR_ID',
    currency: 'GBP',
  });
  paypalSdk.Buttons().render('#paypal-button-container');
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is the way

Comment: And where would you attatch the amount and items to the rendered button?

Answer (score 0):

because your `paypal` variable is not described.

use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-paypal-checkout)

install

```
npm i vue-paypal-checkout
```

import

```
import PayPal from 'vue-paypal-checkout'
```

and now `PayPal` is your variable and it is described

Comment: still button does not showing, and error still display `Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: paypal is not defined"`. Thanks for your reply Sir

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [vue-head](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-head) it loads the script only in the component or view you need it:

install

`npm install vue-head`

Configure globally main.js

```js
import VueHead from "vue-head";
Vue.use(VueHead);
```

and then call it in your component:

```js
<template>
<paypalbutton :import="totalImport" />
</template>
<script>
name: "myComponent",
components: {
    paypalbutton,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      totalImport: "835"
    };
  },
  
  head: {
    script: [
      {
        type: "text/javascript",
        src: "https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js",
      },
    ],
  },
</script>
```

The paypal button file looks like this:

```js
<template>
  <div id="paypal-button"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ["import"],

  mounted() {
    const totalImport = this.import;
    const ClientID =
      "WKAkFn3g4C111Ud3lLaUAfzagvJ_pmkLKBVMASvv6nyjX3fv3j0gtBdJEDhRPznYP9sLtf9oiJfH";
    paypal.Button.render(
      {
        env: "sandbox",
        client: {
          sandbox: ClientID,
        },

        locale: "en_US",
        style: {
          layout: "vertical",
          size: "responsive",
          color: "gold",
          shape: "pill",
          label: "pay",
        },

        commit: true,

        payment: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.payment.create({
            transactions: [
              {
                description: "My happy shipping",
                amount: {
                  total: totalImport,
                  currency: "USD",
                },
              },
            ],
          });
        },

        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
          return actions.payment.execute().then(function () {
            window.alert("Thank you for your purchase!");
          });
        },
      },
      "#paypal-button"
    );

    console.log("Paypal button loaded");
  },
};
</script>
```